# Not able to concatenate two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to concatenate two dataframes (df1, df2) in Pandas (python)
such that the result would contain all the indices (unique and common) of df1 and whatever df2 has but isn't there in df1. An example:

**df1**

```
     col1 col2
0     1   2
1     2   3
2     3   4
```

**df2**

```
     col1 col2
1     4   6
2     2   3
3     5   5
```

I want the result to be like:

```
     col1 col2
0     1   2
1     2   3
2     3   4
3     5   5
```

Comment: So, what's the actual question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [combine_first](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html).

```
df3 = df1.combine_first(df2)

print(df3)
```

yields

```
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     2     3
2     3     4
3     5     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the list of rows you want to get from `df2` and concatenate them to `df1`

```
 ids = [x for x in df2.index if x not in df1.index]
 pd.concat([df1,  df2.ix[ids]])
```